# How to pass variables to mailto method

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I need to know if its possible to pass variables to the mailto: method.

I want to have something along the lines like this, so it opens a new email on outlook.

```
var email = "random@random.random"
var subject = "test"
window.href = "mailto:email?subject=subject"
```

Now i want to know if i can pass these variables. I don't care about the body of the email I just wanna have the email address and the subject line passed in.
I can't ActiveXObject because my code is on the server side rather then the client side so it wont have permission to create objects. Or at least thats what i got from reading into opening outlook from javascripts.

Comment: You replied to your own question. Just use `window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject;`?

Comment: @opatut the problem is that i have tried the expression that you have, and all it does is print the actual +email+ into the email rather than what the variable contains. Do i need something special or am i missing something.

Comment: You are probably mixing or missing quotation marks. They are important!

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF: this works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/CUEEr/

Comment: I guess I'm just missing typing something. I shall let you guys know when I get back to working on this. Thank you

Comment: @opatut hey so I guess i was just missing a quote somewhere. Im not sure what to do about this question then, should I delete it? or just leave it up? with no answers? or should i answer it myself since you basically said I did.

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some quotes somewhere. Make sure your quoting looks similar to this:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject;
```